# Is there a proper way how to create a table with enums for all dialects with JOOQ?

Tags: java, enums, migration, jooq, flyway

I created a JOOQ script which is executed by Flyway to creates a table with one enum. When The scheme is generated into running PostgresSQL instance then generated POJOS enum information gets lost, and the field is just a String.

```java
sl.alterTable("tableName").addColumn("column", SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(MyEnum.class)).execute();

// ...

enum MyEnum implements EnumType {
    A("A"),
    B("B");

    private final String literal;

    MyEnum(String literal) {
        this.literal = literal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLiteral() {
        return literal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return V2020_01_09__table_constant.State.class.getName().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

To generate enum into Java from PostgresSQL database I need to do the following hack and distinguish DB dialect. So I need to treat enums in a special way for every single migration.

```java
if (dsl.dialect().equals(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)) {
    dsl.createType("MyEnum").asEnum("a", "b").execute();
    dsl.alterTable("tableName").addColumn("column", new DefaultDataType<>(null, MyEnum.class, "myenum")).execute();
} else {
    dsl.alterTable("tableName").addColumn("column", SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(MyEnum.class)).execute();
}
```

At last, I replaced H2 which supports enums and everything looks OK. I have enum in Java POJOS. But production database which might be running on PostgresSQL still gets varchars types.

Is there a way how to generate PostgresSQL schema with enums without implicitly saying create my enum type?

Answer (score 1):

> At last, I replaced H2 which supports enums and everything looks OK. I have enum in Java POJOS.

The last time I checked, H2's enum implementation was still missing quite a few things, and we cannot reverse engineer their enums correctly yet, so that won't work well.

> Is there a way how to generate PostgresSQL schema with enums without implicitly saying create my enum type?

There shouldn't be any problem using enums in PostgreSQL, if you connect to an actual database instance for code generation. I suggest removing H2 from the equation if you're going to use vendor specific data types like enums, arrays, etc. Using H2 will just cause pain all the time. I'm assuming you're using H2 for integration testing. I recommend using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) with an actual PostgreSQL database instead.